# What can be the reasons for 90% of samples belong to one cluster when there is 8 clusters?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means

I use the k-means algorithm to clustering set of documents.

(parameters are - number of clusters=8, number of runs for different centroids =10)

The number of documents are 5800

Surprisingly the result for the clustering is

90% of documents belong to cluster - 7 (final cluster)
9% of documents belong to cluster - 0 (first cluster)

and the rest 6 clusters have only a single sample. What might be the reason for this?

Comment: Ask on http://stats.stackexchange.com -- and they'll need more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

K-means clustering attempts to minimize sum of distances between each point and a centroid of a cluster each point belongs to. Therefore, if 90% of your points are close together the sum of distances between those points and the cluster centroid is fairly small, Therefore, the k-means solving algorithm puts a centroid there. Single points are put in their own cluster because they are really far from other points, and a cluster of those points with other points would not be optimal.

Comment: thanks a lot Akavall. i need to find more randomize data

Answer (score 2):

**K-means is highly sensitive to noise!**

Noise, which is farther away from the data, becomes even more influential when your square its deviations. This makes k-means really sensitive to this.

Produce a data set, with 50 points distributed N(0;0.1), 50 points distributed N(1;0.1) and 1 point at 100. Run k-means with k=2, and you are bound to get that one point a cluster, and the two real clusters merged.

It's just how k-means is *supposed* to work: find a least-squared quantization of the data; it does not care about "clumps" in your data set or not.

Now it may often be beneficial (with respect to the least-squares objective) to make one-element clusters if there are outliers (here, you apparently have at least 6 such outliers). In such cases, you may need to increase k by the number of such one-element clusters you get. Or use outlier detection methods, or a clustering algorithm such as DBSCAN which is tolerant wrt. noise.

Comment: That describe the one of biggest problems in my mind .thanks @Anony-Mousse

Answer (score 1):

K-means is indeed sensitive to noise BUT investigate your data! 
Have you pre-processed your "real-data" before applying the distance measure on it? 
Are you sure your distance metric represents proximity as you'll expected?

There are a lot of possible "bugs" that may cause this scenario.. not necessary k-means fault