# What can be the reasons for 95% of samples belong to one cluster when there are 5 clusters?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, k-means

I used the k-means algorithm to clustering set of documents which are textual data only.

The number of documents are 2lack records

Surprisingly the result for the clustering is

95% of records is storing in 1 cluster, remaining records are going to another clusters.

This is not a problem if it chooses correct cluster while predicting the data. I thought this might be the issue behind my problem.

Why this is happening?

Parameters : number of clusters = 5 (used elbow method to know this), random state = 0 or 42 (both used but no use), { init=' kmeans++ ' } also used to but no difference

Here is my code showing how I created vectors

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import _pickle as cPickle

def build_tfidf_vect(series,save_model = True ,) :
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words="english")
    vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(series)
    print("Shape of tfidf matrix: {}".format(vectors.shape))
    if save_model:
        data_struct = {'vectors': vectors, 'vectorizer': vectorizer}
        with open('data_2l.bin', 'wb') as f:
            cPickle.dump(data_struct, f)
    return vectorizer, vectors

import pandas as pd

feed = pd.read_csv('2l_data.csv', encoding='latin')

build_tfidf_vect(feed['Column_name'])
```

```
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans
import scipy

def load_tf_idfvectors():
    import time
    import _pickle as cPickle
    with open(r'C:\Users\data_2l.bin', 'rb') as f:
        data_struct = cPickle.load(f)
        vectors,vectorizer = data_struct['vectors'], data_struct['vectorizer']
    return vectorizer,vectors

def dump(cluster_0,cluster_1,cluster_2,cluster_3,cluster_4):
    save_model=True
    if save_model:
        data_struct = {'cluster0': cluster_0, 'cluster1': cluster_1,'cluster2': cluster_2, 'cluster3': cluster_3,'cluster4': cluster_4}
        with open(r'C:\Users\totalclusters_2l.bin', 'wb') as f:
            cPickle.dump(data_struct, f)

import pandas as pd
import pickle
data=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\New_vectors_data_2l.csv", encoding="latin")
tfidf_vectorizer,tfidf=load_tf_idfvectors()

kmeans = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=5, init= 'k-means++',random_state=0).fit(tfidf)
labels = kmeans.fit_predict(tfidf)
X_n=pd.DataFrame(tfidf,columns=['tf-idf'])
labels_n=pd.DataFrame(labels,columns=['cl_n'])
result = pd.concat([data['Column_name'],X_n,labels_n])
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: it would be useful if you'd share what similarity measure you used, and how you computed your document vectors, and maybe some sample doc. if most docs end up in the same cluster, it's likely because they are similar for that measure, and the other 4 clusters are just picking up outliers.

Comment: To add to what MrE wrote: There's probably a discrepancy between how you were able to determine that "there is 5 clusters" and how you are asking your clustering algorithm to determine clusters. What constitutes a cluster depends on choices that you make, such as the metric/dissimilarity used, and rules for determining when one cluster ends and another begins. You should take a step back and make sure that you are mathematically clear about how *you* are determining that there is supposed to be five clusters.

Comment: This isn't a programming question, it's a machine learning question. Please ask it on another Stack Exchange, such as Data Science or Cross Validated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can be the reasons for 90% of samples belong to one cluster when there is 8 clusters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26793585/what-can-be-the-reasons-for-90-of-samples-belong-to-one-cluster-when-there-is-8)

Answer (score 0):

Try normalizing your data. K-means clustering is "isotropic" in all directions of space and therefore tends to produce more or less round (rather than elongated) clusters. In this situation leaving variances unequal is equivalent to putting more weight on variables with smaller variance.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html